# What are the election vans called?

Tags: word-requests, english-to-japanese

Vans with cute girls, loud speakers, and political candidates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are usually called **選挙カー**. Another name for this is 選挙運動車【せんきょうんどうしゃ】, according to Wikipedia, but ordinary people rarely see this term.

Such vans without candidates but with a large ad on them are called 宣伝カー or 広告カー.

Comment: This has no bearing on anything, but I accidentally read 選挙カー as せんきょりょくいち.

Comment: @Nothingatall ﾎﾎホﾎｵ…